eject HDD 2.5" in Windows 10
I finished copying the files to my 2.5" external HDD (HDD 2.5 + Orico or kesu case). I ejected the HDD in Windows 10 but the enclosure case LED was on and then I went to pull the USB 3.0 cable but when the cable came out of the PC port my hand hit the side of the HDD case and the case moved slightly to the right of the table. Did this event cause damage to the HDD?

We don't know, and we can't know. Do you have reason to suspect it caused damage? Do you have any sort of gauge or measure how hard you jostled the drive's enclosure? Is this an SSD, or a "spinning" HDD? Please EDIT your post to improve and clarify it.

An HDD will have an operating shock resistance in excess of 10 g. You are very unlikely to have hit it that hard with a hand.

case moved slightly ... what does this mean

you are asking a technical question about an unknown event

If you properly ejected the drive from Windows, then the hard drive would have flushed all the data to the disk.  The actuator arm - which holds the write magnets - would have moved to the park position as well.  Data should not have been corrupted, nor should the head have crashed into the platters.  Of course, this assuming this is a mechanical hard disk drive (AKA spinning rust).  If it is a SSD based drive, then its virtually impossible to hit it and cause damage to the drive itself.

The last sentence is one of the few cases where you can safely write "completely impossible" instead of "virtually impossible"!

Whether or not the USB HDD has parked its head after software ejection depends on the USB-to-SATA controller used in the case. Quite a few don't spin down the drive.
In any case, you'd want to wait a few seconds after unplugging to make sure it's spun down unless you've heard it doing so on eject. If you bump the HDD before it's spun down and parked the heads then you likely cause permanent damage to the disk. If you're not sure what happened you should run a surface scan.

my enclosurer cases orico 25PW1 and Kesu 2530 uses controller chip JMicron JMS578

You can test the controller by simply putting an ear on the HDD while soft ejecting it.

I didn't hear anything, after ejecting the enclosure LED remains On without blinking

Do the model, brand, chip of the USB3.0 enclosure case and Windows power settings have any relation to the parking of the heads of a 2.5" HDD + enclosure usb3.0 after the Windows "safely remove hardware" eject command is completed and the letter E: disappears from the system without disconnect usb cable after eject in windows? my enclosures usb3.0 kesu 2530 and orico 25pw1 uses jmicron jms578 chip
